# C programming: BEOWULF cluster : for multi core multi thread : MPI vs pthread

Tags: c, ubuntu, pthreads, mpi

I have 50 Desktop Computer available (with i5), each running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
I need to compute probability of some event through C code with samples of size at least 2^45. Clearly running the C code on a single computer is not an option. I can do it manually by independently running the C code at each of the computers for each core and then combine the result. The process is laborious. Also I have to make sure that each C code is ran with different random seeds.

The Desktop computers are set upped for password-less ssh for root users i.e., root user of any computer has password-less access to the root user of any other computer including itself.

I have googled about pthread.h and MPI. But could not figure out how to use all available core to get the job done. Any suggestion will be welcomed.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're actually asking:  whether to use pthreads or MPI?  How to use pthreads?  How to use MPI?  You could even use both, with MPI to handle distributing the job among the 50 computers, and threads to utilize all the cores on each computer.

Comment: FWIW, if this is a one-time job, it may be quicker to just manually start lots of processes; it may be tedious, but it'll probably take less time than learning an API like pthreads or MPI and modifying your program to use it.  But if you'll need to run more jobs like this in the future, it's probably worth taking the time to add parallelization support to the program.

Comment: Yes I need to do that many times in the future. My Question is whether it is possible to run a single c code in a master node and use pthread.h or MPI or whatever it requires to do the job done.

Comment: Voting to close as too brad, but yes you can do that with MPI, but you will have to study it yourself, asking for a full tutorial is too much. Don't bother with pthreads for a cluster.

Answer (score 0):

This may be too late, but if you're still in the tinkering phases perhaps openMP may be better suited for your needs.   Pthreads have minimal built-in support infrastructure, whereas something like openMP provides a mix of the precompiled well supported MPI libraries with less of the installation overhead.

Just a suggestion